# Passing service between controllers and directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a single service defined as follows:

```
 angular.module('myApp')
     .factory('myService', function ($resource, $q) {
         mySource = [];
         EndPoint = $resource('/my/api/endpoint', {});
         return({
              getSourceAsFunction: function(){
                  return(mySource);
              }
              ,getSourceAsValue: mySource,
              ,setSource: function(newSource){
                     mySource=newSource;
              }
              ,fetchSource: function(attributes){
                  request = $q.defer
                  EndPoint.get(attributes
                  ,function(success){
                          request.resolve(success.data);
                          //mySource['headersArray'] = success.data['headersArray'];
                          //mySource['footersArray'] = success.data['footersArray'];
                  },function(failure){
                          request.reject(failure);
                  });
                  request.promise
           });
      });
```

This service is then injected in multiple controllers, on various directives (some of which have isolate scope). In only one of them (as of right now), is the fetch (and resulting set) operation actually executed, but the fetch operation could be executed repeatedly by a user through a click interaction.

The other controllers bind like so:

```
      $scope.fooVar = myService.getSourceasValue;
```

or

```
      $scope.fooVar = myService.getSourceAsFunction();
```

In both cases the variable does not automatically update when the value in the service is changed.

Setting up a `$watch` like so:

```
       $scope.$watch('fooVar', function(newVal, oldVal){console.log('hi')}, true);
```

Also never triggers (in both cases).

The two commented lines in the resource callback:

```
       //mySource['headersArray'] = success.data['headersArray'];
       //mySource['footersArray'] = success.data['footersArray'];
```

mySource was at that point instantiated as `{}`. This did not fix the issue.

Were the previous attempt to try and reuse the same object.

One way I have found to get around this limitation is to set up a $watch like so:

```
       $scope.$watch(function(){return(myService.getSourceAsFunction())}
                  , function(newVal, oldVal){console.log('hi'), true)};
```

However, I find this worrying since I do not want this function to continually run in the background. (How does that work? How often does that function run? How many `$digest` iterations does that trigger? Just how (in)efficient is that solution?)

How can I get around this? How can I bind to a service variable "by reference" if you will?

Might there be a better approach? I have attempted events, however as some of these elements are siblings, this results in an overly complex chain, where a child might `$emit` up to have a listener on a joint parent catch an event and `$broadcast` back down.

What other approaches are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is, set your service under the scope, I.E. $scope.myService = myService and then you can access it straight from the HTML.

You will also need to send the $scope to your service so once it fetches the data you can run $scope.$apply().

The problem right now is that you're setting it when the controller initialized. The controller will not be initialized again and therefore it will never update.

$watch will only be updated once the scope is $digest'd. See the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

Comment: this is an interesting idea. I'll have to try this tomorrow. Would this work with the setSource method defined above? eg, if controller A calls setSource, would controller B which defines $scope.myService pick up on this?

I'll try this tomorrow (when I'm no longer drinking), but this sounds like it just might work...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best guess, why binding is not working.

Initially you are setting the array to

```
mySource = [];
```

Later you replace the reference when the data comes from the server.

```
mySource = success.data;
```

Instead can you try `mySource.push` method to update data in the intial array.

Also just wanted to point out that the first $watch expression should take the first parameter as variable name string rather than the variable itself.

Comment: is this for the getAsValue, getAsFunction, or agnostic to either? So what I would then do is something like mySource.splice(0) mySource.push etc.
Wouldn't that necessitate iterating over the success.data array and pushing each element individually? Wouldn't this be really inefficient?
Also, thanks for pointing out the typo. Its been fixed.

Comment: It is same for function and value. I need to think about a more efficient solution

Comment: When i think about efficient, the solution may be little inefficient but, it would hardly matter, unless the array is very large. You can also try to return a complex object such as `{mySource:data}` and this should work with $watch. But i think simple clear, push, splice method would work.

Comment: Having gone back and looked at the code, instantiating it as an object rather then an array, and setting keys on the object directly were both things that I had tried, and neither one of them fixed the issue. In fact, even at present, it isn't really populated as an array, but as an object, the initial [] initialization is justa placeholder and has been replaced with {} to no effect.